# How could I set a private svelte variable for the unit testing?

Tags: mocking, svelte, private, testing-library

How could I set a private svelte variable for the unit testing?

E.g. I have the component:

```
//a.svelte
<script>
    let a = "b";
</script>

<div data-testid="c">{a}</div>
```

And I am trying to test the component:

```
import { screen } from "@testing-library/svelte";
import a from "./a.svelte;

...

//arrange
const aMock = "d";

//act
render(a);

//assert
expect(screen.getByTestId("c").textContent).toBe("d");
```

How can I set the `a` inside the `a.svelte`? I do not want to make the `a` a property, i.e. I do not want to do the `export let a = "b";`. I want to keep `a` as an internal state of the component, but I would like to mock it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compile with the `dev` flag, you will get additional functions on the component for capturing and setting component state, e.g. the default REPL with its `name` state generates:

```js
$$self.$capture_state = () => ({ name });

$$self.$inject_state = $$props => {
    if ('name' in $$props) $$invalidate(0, name = $$props.name);
};

if ($$props && "$$inject" in $$props) {
    $$self.$inject_state($$props.$$inject);
}
```

You can also inject an initial state via `$$inject` as part of the props.

Since local state usually *cannot* be changed from outside, the compiler will not generate any render update code unless the local variable is assigned somewhere. A dummy assignment (`a = a`) could be used to ensure that.

Example of both setting a different initial state and updating it later:

```html
<script>
    import Component from './Component.svelte';

    let c;
    let newName = '';
    
    function mount(node) {
        c = new Component({
            target: node,
            props: { $$inject: { name: 'Steve' } },
        });

        return {
            destroy() { c.$destroy(); }
        };
    }

    function changeName() {
        c.$inject_state({ name: newName });
    }
</script>

<div use:mount />

<input bind:value={newName} />
<button on:click={changeName}>Change</button>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/1c471f2f7a714d25b7400e0cae5fae73?version=4.2.1)

Comment: Is there a documentation somewhere about it? E.g. the `$capture_state` seems to work, but would be nice to know how it works and what it does.

Comment: So, how could I change the `a` inside my component? It is not very clear from your example? Which approach out of those three should I use?

Comment: There is no documentation on this as far as I know, it may not be safe to rely on this. It is used by official tooling, especially for hot-module replacement, it captures state, loads the updated module, constructs the new component and injects the state again. Did you figure out how to use the functions, since the answer is accepted?

Comment: No, I did not. I am still not able to mock the `a`.

Comment: I added some additional explanation and an example.